# Finding a bearing using destPoint from a previous bearing

Tags: r, function, recursion

I'm trying to build some code to find the final bearings for successive positions and distances from an initial bearing. I'm using destPoint, however struggling to integrate it into some sort of recursive function. (if that's what I need)

I've tried recursive functions but nothing seems to be close.

Here's essentially what I'm trying to achieve manually, but I have a lot more data and would love to figure out how to do this!

```r
init<-c(149.6566667, -36.01983333)
bearing<-c(270, 315, 10, 20)
distance<-c(5,5,2,2)

a<-destPoint(init,bearing[1],distance[1])
a
b<-destPoint(a, bearing[2],distance[2])
b
c<-destPoint(b, bearing[3], distance[3])
c
d<-destPoint(c, bearing[4], distance[4])
d
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`accumulate2` from `purrr` can be used

```
library(geosphere)
library(purrr)
accumulate2(bearing, distance, destPoint, .init = init)[-1]
#[[1]]
#          lon       lat
#[1,] 149.6566 -36.01983

#[[2]]
#          lon      lat
#[1,] 149.6566 -36.0198

#[[3]]
#          lon       lat
#[1,] 149.6566 -36.01978

#[[4]]
#          lon       lat
#[1,] 149.6566 -36.01977
```